# Omitting singularities from plot by specifying them in range

Tags: plotting

See the Mathematica 'basic plotting' documentation:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BasicPlotting.html

Scroll down to the third plot on that page, which says the following:
"The singularities can be omitted from the plot by specifying them in the plot's range."

According to this doc, if you enter this in Mathematica 9, you will get the result shown in that doc page:

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -3, -Pi/2, Pi/2, 3}]
```

But when I try it I get this `pllim` error:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

claiming too many things appearing after `x`, but that's what the doc says to do. I have searched here for anything relevant to no avail. What's going on with this?

Comment: confirmed on 9.01 on Windows... and even the documentation marks the additional arguments in red.

Comment: Works in v7.  Fails in in 8.0.4.

Comment: You could also (cross-)post this on community.wolfram.com, which may help to get WRI attention more quickly. Using the `Exclusions` option works, but I guess that is not your point.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a documentation issue. The desired plot can be obtained using:

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> {-Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```